# LDAP Query to return list of users which contain specific attributes

Tags: ldap, ldap-query

In this `OU=Employees,OU=Users,DC=org,DC=com` I have a list of CN (user1, user2, user3. Each CN (user) contains a list of attributes (isUseless, managerid, etc.)

I want to obtain a list of all CN Employees, whos attribute `isUseless=Yes`.

I've searched all over the web and read countless tutorials, but am struggling to understand probably some basic concepts here. I would really apprecaite if someone could break down the solution for me.

Comment: Please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Of all employees, or only the ones in the first list? If the former, why mention the latter? If the latter, why mention 'all employees'?

Comment: more downvotes plz

Answer (score 0):

A LDAP Search filter similar to:

```
(&(isUseless=Yes)(|(cn= user1)(cn= user1)(cn=user1)))
```

or for all entries with cn values:
    (&(isUseless=Yes)(cn=*))
or for all user type entries (in Microsoft Active Directory:

```
(&(isUseless=Yes)(sAMAccountType=805306368))
```

Specifying the:
returned attributes: "isUseless" "managerid" "etc"
baseDN: OU=Employees,OU=Users,DC=org,DC=com

Should do the trick.

Let me know how I can help.
-jim

Comment: Hey Jim, I tried using this query, and repalced "user1" with the CN name, but still didn't work. In any case, is it possible to query across all CN instead of specific CN (users)? For example: (&(isUseless=Yes)(|(cn=*)) Is this suppose to return all CNs in OU=Employees which contain the attribute "isUseless=Yes"?

Comment: The format `(&(isUseless=Yes)(objectClass=user))` worked for me.